# C++ Question about two class constructors

Tags: c++, constructor

My teacher gave me a sample code, but I'm a bit confused.

```
class CBook
{
...
    pubic:
        CBook();
        CBook(string Title, string Auther, int Year); // I know this is the constructor
        ~CBook(); // and this is the destructor
};
```

I wish to know the use of `CBook();`, is this line of code really necessary?

Thanks

Comment: You should take a look at a good book [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: `I know this is the constructor` is not **the** constructor but **a** constructor (there can be more than one). So `CBook()` is also a constructor.

Comment: @t.niese Okay, will do . Thanks. Sorry I've 0 concept about objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually compiler will call this constructor in case you will do like that:

```
CBook obj;
```

in another words, you will not pass any arguments to it.

So, if you delete it and try for example:

```
CBook obj;
```

compiler will give you an error like "no default constructor"

Sometimes we need object without any of its members filled to fill the later.